# Different favicon for routs on react webapp

Tags: reactjs, favicon

For my react app I have two urls ‘app/’ and ‘app/en’. My customer wants a different logo when adding a link to the home screen. My current solution is to have two deployments of the app for each of the routs.

Does anyone have an Idea how to avoid the ‘double deployment’ ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the fact that the DOM will have a link tag which helps decide the favicon of the web page.

For CRA:

If you notice `public/index.html`, you can find something like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
```

You will have to react out for this html tag and update it in your react router related componen. Since it is a side effect, please put it inside `useEffect`:

Example:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let link = document.querySelector("link[rel='shortcut icon']");
    link.href =
      "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/faviconV2?url=https://en.wikipedia.org&client=IMAGE_SEARCH&size=24&type=FAVICON&fallback_opts=TYPE,SIZE,UR";
  }, []);
```

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-router-v6-forked-vyyygv?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A3%2C1) and a [demo](https://vyyygv.csb.app/apple).

The above is a very generic code, but i hope it helps you and you can use it to adapt it to your router based solution.
Maybe put it inside the top most ancestor component of your `/en` route.